# Fetch Wordpress API data into Angular 7

Tags: angular, wordpress

I want to use Wordpress as a backend(just for CMS), I'm trying to pull in the post data into my angular 7 app but the post information is not showing. I can see the data in the console but I'm unable to pull in the data in my component. Any suggestions?

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'altair-global';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Make the HTTP request:
    this.http.get('http://altair-global.local/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=50').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

insight.component.ts

```
<div class="container">
  <h4 class="text-center">Insight Page</h4>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
      <h4>{{ post.title.rendered }}</h4>
      {{ post.date_gmt | date }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: could you update your example where you actually assign the http call to your component variable ? in this example, `posts` are undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the api call as a service first. Create api.service.ts

```
export  class  APIService {
    constructor(private  httpClient:  HttpClient) {}
    getPosts(){
      return  this.httpClient.get('http://altair-global.local/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=50');
    }
}
```

Import it into your insight.component.ts file like so:

```
import { APIService } from  '../api.service'; (file path may vary)
```

Your insights.component should look similar to this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from  '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from  '../api.service';

@Component({
    selector:  'app-insights',
    templateUrl:  './insight.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./insight.component.css']
})

export  class  InsightComponent  implements  OnInit {

    private  posts:  Array<object> = [];
    constructor(private  apiService:  APIService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getPosts();
    }
    public  getPosts(){
        this.apiService.getPosts().subscribe((data:  Array<object>) => {
            this.posts  =  data;
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

this will help you:

first you need to decalre:

```
posts: any;
```

Then into your http code:

```
this.posts = data;
console.log(this.posts);
```

for more info : [Fetch Wordpress API data into Angular](https://therichpost.com/get-wordpress-data-angular2-wordpress-rest-api)